# RewriteRule php to html extension

Tags: .htaccess

how to write RewriteRule to access php file as html extension, the mark file is located inside folder called domain.com/markfolder/mark.php

and i got following in my root directory

```
 Options +FollowSymlinks

 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /
 RedirectMatch 301 (.*)\.html$ $1.php
```

---

and below file i try to locate inside domain.com/markfolder/.htaccess

try 1

```
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteRule ^mark\.php$ mark.html [NC,R]
```

try 2

```
 RewriteEngine on 
 RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html $1\.php
```

try 3

```
 Options +FollowSymlinks
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteRule ^(.+)\.html$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

above three try simple doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

First, your htaccess file in your root directory is causing the problem. It's redirecting `.html` to `.php` and is part of mod_alias, not mod_rewrite. This means requests will get processed by both the `RedirectMatch` as well as any rewrite rules. So first change your root htaccess to:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ $1.php [L,R=301]
```

Not sure why you want to permanently redirect, since this will affect all requests even requests in subdirectories. It seems like it's not what you want and will only break any attempt for you to rewrite.

Then in the htaccess file in your markfolder:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ $1.php [L]
```